# Excel Grouping and count

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I have a data set, that after some filtering and applying some formulas, it gives me the date the task was created and how long it took to complete in days.

[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTjtY.png)

[how i want data to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFhkV.png)

Comment: I would try with COUNTIF() function, where you can declare a string "1 Day".
https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function

I would also consider the table transposition.

Answer (score 1):

If your data were in A1:B10 and your table in D1:H9, you could use:

```
=SUM(($A$1:$A$10<=$D2)*($A$1:$A$10>=($D2-6))*(VALUE(LEFT($B$1:$B$10,FIND(" ",$B$1:$B$10)-1))=COLUMN()-4))
```

for the first three columns and

```
=SUM(($A$1:$A$10<=$D2)*($A$1:$A$10>=($D2-6))*(VALUE(LEFT($B$1:$B$10,FIND(" ",$B$1:$B$10)-1))>=COLUMN()-4))
```

for the 3+ Days column.

(The only difference between the first three columns and the fourth is the `>=` at the end (`... >=COLUMN()-4))` . That is due to there being more than a single value for the number of days a qualifying entry might have:  4, 5, 404, 28, whatever, just not 1, 2, or 3.)

This is an older technique, sometimes easier to use though than `COUNTIFS()` which would be the natural function to try given having more than one criteria. It makes an internal (to the formula) array out of each `Range = Some criteria` clause. Those array values are all `TRUE` or `FALSE` results, but the arithmetic operation on them, multiplication here, forces ("coerces" in Excel-speak) them into being 1's and 0's. If you had a single test, you'd want to place the entire test inside parentheses and multiply it by 1. But multiplying by other test result arrays does the trick here.

Since you want `AND` you multiply those result arrays. If you wanted `OR` you'd add them to each other. Excel treats any value other than 0 as `TRUE` so 12 tests all `TRUE` equalling 12 would simply be a `TRUE` to Excel, no errors for not being a 1. So if an entry doesn't meet one or more conditions, it would yield a 0 so no matter whether it produced matches or not on the rest, the multiplication would yield 0 and therefore no match overall.

`SUM()`'s purpose in the formula is to collapse the resulting internal array. That's always been needed, but nowadays it mainly prevents a `Spill` error. You want a single entry in each cell, so you defintely do NOT want a `Spill` result, and in older versions it added up all the entries in the result array giving right answers. Without it, only the first entry in the result array would be reported out in the cell and only coincidence would have made any result correct.

Particular to your problem, the date conditions. You have what looks like a date for the end of a period, and implying that they cover weeks since the dates are all seven days apart. So you can set one condition to be "less than or equal to the shown date" and a second condition to be "greater than or equal to six days less than the shown date" which will capture all entries in each week you list.

The last condition above is found from the form of your entries. One could use `SUBSTITUTE()` instead, well, two of them with one "wrapping" the other, to remove " Days" first (inner one), then " Day" (outer one) (wrapping them the other way would leave just an "s" to remove which ought to be fine for your entries, but as a general thing, you'd want a LOT more certainty... so you'd do the longer one, then the shorter one. `FIND()` though takes all the hassle out of it by seeking that first space character and taking just what's to the left of it, then `VALUE()` turns the `LEFT()`'s output of text back into numbers for easy comparison.

You could "slickify" the formula and likely get it down to a single formula, not two like here, but I didn't have time. One way to do a slighlty different "slickification" would be to replace the `COLUMN()-4` part with `COLUMN()-@COLUMN($D$1:$H$9)` (I used D1:H9 for my setup) and could, of course, use `LET()` to set up your variable information like the entry dates and the column for time taken, that way putting the variable portions of th formula all at the front of it so they can be easily found and changed when necessary.

However, slick or not, these two formulas will do the trick. Another advantage of this approach is you can have as many conditions as you can fit into Excel's formula length limits, not "just the" 127 offered by `COUNTIFS()`. (Of course, someone probably needs that for some arcane purpose, but most anyone else would never.)